# Why does this sorting cause an infinite digest error?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-digest

Here's the architecture: I have a controller and a service. The controller can call to the service and sort it's data. I have a service method `setSort` that simply sets a variable in the service. The controller watches the data in the service. If a sort is active, I get an infinite digest error. Demo: http://jsbin.com/berujec/edit?js,output

```js
/**
* Angular fast-changing data with sort
*/

console.clear();


angular.module('app', [])

.controller('main', function($scope, dataSvc, $timeout) {
    $scope.items = dataSvc.generateData().getData();
 
 $scope.$watch(dataSvc.getData, function(curr, orig) {
  if(curr !== orig) {
   $scope.items = curr;
  }
 });
 
 var toggle = true;
 $scope.onClick = function() {
  dataSvc.setSort( toggle ? 'asc' : 'desc' );
  toggle = !toggle;
 };
})

.factory('dataSvc', function() {
  
 var data = [];
 var sort;
 var limit = 50;
 
 //use US state names just for fun
 var states = ["alabama", "alaska", "american samoa", "arizona", "arkansas", "california", "colorado", "connecticut", "delaware", "district of columbia", "federated states of micronesia", "florida", "georgia", "guam", "hawaii", "idaho", "illinois", "indiana", "iowa", "kansas", "kentucky", "louisiana", "maine", "marshall islands", "maryland", "massachusetts", "michigan", "minnesota", "mississippi", "missouri", "montana", "nebraska", "nevada", "new hampshire", "new jersey", "new mexico", "new york", "north carolina", "north dakota", "northern mariana islands", "ohio", "oklahoma", "oregon", "palau", "pennsylvania", "puerto rico", "rhode island", "south carolina", "south dakota", "tennessee", "texas", "utah", "vermont", "virgin islands", "virginia", "washington", "west virginia", "wisconsin", "wyoming"];
 
 function generateData(limit) {
  var n = 0;
  var data = [];
  while(n < limit) {
   n++;
   data.push({
    id: states[n], //these are stable, always same
    score: Math.round(100 * Math.random()) //random
   });
  }
  return data;
 }
 
 function sortBy() {
  data = _.sortByOrder(data, ['score'], [sort]);
 }
 
 
 var svc = {
     
  getData: function() {
   if(sort) {
    sortBy(sort);
   }
   return data;
  },
  
  generateData: function() {
   data = generateData(limit);
   return this;
  },
  
  setSort: function(order) {
      sort = order;
   return this;
  }
  
 };

 return svc;
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/lodash/lodash/3.10.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="main">
   <button ng-click="onClick()">Toggle Sort</button>
    <ul>
  <li ng-repeat="item in items track by item.id">
          {{ item.id }}<br>
    {{ item.score }}
  </li>
 </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

To reproduce the `infdig` error:

1. Open console.
2. Click Toggle Sort.

What is causing the infinite digest to occur?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/infdig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dataSvc.getData()` function you are watching returns a different object every time. Angular will keep running digest cycles until everything it is watching doesn't change. You can fix this by getting rid of the `$watch`. http://jsbin.com/fakijiqujo/1/edit?console,output

JS

```
$scope.getItems = function() {
  return dataSvc.getData();
};
```

HTML

```
<li ng-repeat="item in getItems() track by item.id">
```

Comment: Using `watchCollection` also works as well. I thought that it was returning the same array each time because because `sort` sorts in place and returns the same array, e.g. `var arr = [3,2,1]; arr.sort() === arr.sort(); //=> true`. That's not the case with `_.sortByOrder`.